# Laravel policy not applying to model automatically

Tags: php, laravel

According to the Laravel docs, a policy should be auto-discovered if it follows naming conventions: it should be placed in the `Policies` directory, its name should be the model name plus the word `Policy` and the models should be in the `app` directory. This is all true in my case, but the policy isn't working.

The model name is `Screen`. The policy is named `ScreenPolicy`:

```
class ScreenPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function delete(User $user, Screen $screen)
    {
        return false;    //always return false for testing
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I have the following method that deletes a `Screen`:

```
public function delete(Request $request) {
    $screen = Screen::find($request->screen_id);
    $screen->delete();
    ...
}
```

My expectation is that I shouldn't be able to delete the `Screen` here since the policy always returns false, however the `Screen` is successfully deleted by calling this method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to call the authorize(). Check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers)

```
$screen = Screen::find($id);
if ($this->authorize('delete', $screen)) {
   $screen->delete();
}
```